# How to make buttons visible in odoo after checking some condition?

Tags: python, odoo

```
<button string="Merge" name="merge_beneficiaries" type="object" class="oe_highlight" 
attrs="{'invisible': ['|', '|', ('stage_id', '!=', 2),('active', '=', False)]}"/>
```

I have this button and want to appear only when there are some id's present in many2many field 'duplicate_beneficiaries__ids'.

```
duplicate_beneficiaries_ids = fields.Many2many(
        "openg2p.beneficiary",
        string='Potential Duplicates'
    )
```

Comment: Try this `('duplicate_beneficiaries__ids', '=', [])` if I remember m2m fields are stored as list of commands in the client side, using `False` will not work in attrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Bhavesh Odedra's answer is not working, you can create another boolean computed field in the model to apply button viewing logic in python code, for example:

```
    view_merge_beneficiaries = fields.Boolean(compute='_get_view_merge_beneficiaries')

    def _get_view_merge_beneficiaries(self):
        for record in self:
            record.view_merge_beneficiaries = bool(record.duplicate_beneficiaries_ids)
    
    <field name="view_merge_beneficiaries" invisible="1" />
    <button string="Merge" name="merge_beneficiaries" type="object" class="oe_highlight" 
attrs="{'invisible': [('view_merge_beneficiaries', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Comment: thanks both Charif DZ and your's answer worked :)

Comment: thanks, Charif DZs code seems more elegant and less code.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it like

> attrs="{'invisible': [('duplicate_beneficiaries_ids', '=', False)]}"

And JFI, instead of using *id* on the attrs, we can use *name* like

> attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('stage_id.name', '!=', 'Stage Name'), ('active', '=', False)]}"

Comment: thanks for replying;
The first one did not work when id's were present in 'duplicate_beneficiaries_ids' field and the second one it checks stage name for displaying button but i want  to show the button only when id's are present in 'duplicate_beneficiaries_ids' field.

Comment: @truthfool I edited answer. JFI, answer for your question is 1st section and 2nd section is just for your reference/better practice.

Comment: Ok.But the first one did not work when i added some ids to that many2many field